FindElementById().click will close the browser
I am trying to check a box as shown below. My Code will run without an error but visibly nothing happens on the webpage and it will close the browser. Not sure if I am clicking on the right element.

Here is my code.
   Sub LNExtraction()
        Dim url As String
    
        url = "My-URL"
    
        With New WebDriver
            .Start "edge"
            .Get url
            .Wait 20000
            .SwitchToFrame .FindElementByTag("iframe", timeout:=10000)
            .FindElementById("whinh2120m000-grid-n1-select-header").Click
        End With
    End Sub

Here is the Html

The html content is within an iframe tag.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. This includes HTML.

Update:
I had to add a wait time to see the changes.
Sub LNExtraction()
    Dim url As String

    url = "My-URL"
    
    With New WebDriver
        .Start "edge"
        .Get url
        .FindElementByXPath(".//div[@data-test-id='XXXX']").Click
        .Wait 20000
        .SwitchToFrame .FindElementByTag("iframe", timeout:=10000)
        .FindElementById("whinh2120m000-grid-n1-select-header").Click
        .Wait 90000
        .FindElementById("whinh2120m000-button-std-ssi.export.d").Click
        .Wait 90000
    End With

End Sub

